# Keras Embedding layer activation function?

Tags: keras, embedding, tf.keras

In the fully connected hidden layer of Keras embedding, what is the activation function leveraged? I'm either misunderstanding the concept of this class or unable to find documentation. I understand that it is encoding from word to real-valued vector of dimension *d* via answers like the below on stackoverflow:

> Embedding layers in Keras are trained just like any other layer in your network architecture: they are tuned to minimize the loss function by using the selected optimization method. The major difference with other layers, is that their output is not a mathematical function of the input. Instead the input to the layer is used to index a table with the embedding vectors [1]. However, the underlying automatic differentiation engine has no problem to optimize these vectors to minimize the loss function...

In my network, I have a word embedding portion that is then linked to a larger network that is predicting a binary outcome (e.g., click yes/no). I understand that this Keras embedding is not operating like word2vec because here my embedding is being trained and updated against my end cross-entropy function. But, there is no mention of how the embedding fully-connected layer is activated. Thanks!

Comment: You are misunderstanding, there is no activation used.

Comment: Well, then there would still be an activation, it's just linear. So 1*weight as the output of the hidden layer?

Comment: No, there is no hidden layer or fully connected layers inside, check it for yourself: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/embeddings.py#L144

Comment: "Turns positive integers (indexes) into dense vectors of fixed size. eg. [[4], [20]] -> [[0.25, 0.1], [0.6, -0.2]]". How is it mapping from real-valued number to output vector of dimension d then if not via a connected hidden layer?

Comment: Using K.gather, just like the code I linked

Comment: I'm trying to follow the code. Getting a little confused...

If there is no connection, how are the embeddings learned? Appreciate any additional explanation. Example, we are transforming to some dimensional space according to some cost function + backprop. How are updates to the embeddings taking place if they are not connected?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro excuse me, the comment above should have been "if not via a *fully connected layer*"

I'm still not following how there isn't a fully connected layer involved :)

Comment: I didn't say there was no connection, I said it was not a fully connected layer or a hidden layer.